# Website and admin page are not loading

Tags: plugins

I activated some plugins for my website and now I can't access my website or the wp admin page. error 500

Comment: try disable your plugin from FTP, rename all the plugin folder you have activated then remove it once you know which plugin is causing problem

Comment: enable WP_DEBUG or check error_log.

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question. Not all plugins are safe to use and valid, or well programmed. One (or more) of the plugins you are using is broken, and without `error_reporting` you can't tell which one. Open your error logs to find out.

Regardless of the error logs, remove the plugins you installed and add them back one by one until you find the culprit plugin and skip using it, and possible let the developer know what's happening.

Unfortunately since your `wp-admin` isn't loading, you will need to do this via FTP or your hosting account (WHM, cPanel, etc.)